# How to run Glassfish on Java 9?

Tags: command-line, server, java, application-development, glassfish

As I recall, it's just a matter of invoking `asadmin` to enter the `asadmin` shell:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-5.0/glassfish5/bin/asadmin 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContainer.java:217)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContainer.java:255)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:371)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:306)
    at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:57)
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ java -version
openjdk version "9.0.0.15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu build 9.0.0.15+181)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu build 9.0.0.15+181, mixed mode)
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ javac -version
javac 9.0.0.15
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=artful
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.10"
thufir@dur:~$
```

I've also tried directly entering `list-domains` as well as a few other commands -- all crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GlassFish 5 doesn't support JDK 9 yet. Work on supporting JDK 9 is ongoing and will be part of the version 5.0.1 - see the notice at https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download

[Payara Server](https://www.payara.fish/upstream_builds), an actively maintained fork of GlassFish, runs on JDK 9 since version `5 - Alpha 2`. This is a pre-release and not yet fully tested but if you need JDK 9 support it's probably the only released server that does it until GlassFish 5.0.1 is out.

Comment: doh.  I mean, I should've figured that out.  Thanks.  I wonder whether it's possible to "downgrade" the JVM but keep Java 9...

Comment: With Java 9 you need JDK 9, they are coupled. I've just updated my answer to mention Payara Server which supports JDK 9 in the latest Alpha release.